Upper bound on Gaussian Integral from 0 to x, divided by x
I am looking for upper bounds on
$$F(x) = \frac{1}{x} \int_{0}^x e^{-t^2/2} dt$$
in terms of $x$. Obviously, $F(x) \le \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2x}$, but can we get faster decay in terms of $x$?

For $x>1$,
$$\int_0^x\mathrm e^{-t^2/2},\mathrm dt\ge\int_0^1\mathrm e^{-t^2/2},\mathrm dt\ge\int_0^1\mathrm e^{-1/2},\mathrm dt=\mathrm e^{-1/2}>0,$$
so $F(x)$ is really of order $\frac1x$ when $x$ is large.

if $x>2$, you can bound $\exp(-t^2/2)$ with $\exp(-t/2)$

Your function is:
$$F(x) = \frac{1}{x} \int_{0}^x \text{e}^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} \text{d}t = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cdot\frac{\text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{x}$$
You can use the following known inequality (see this post):
$$\text{erf}(x) \leq \sqrt{1-\text{e}^{-\frac{4}{\pi}x^2}}$$
such that
$$\text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \leq \sqrt{1-\text{e}^{-\frac{2}{\pi}x^2}}$$
and you end up with:
$$F(x)\leq \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{1-\text{e}^{-\frac{2}{\pi}x^2}}}{x}$$
for $x>0$.
